# Regex matching issue on newer version of Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I've moved over to a new server, with **Perl 5.22.1**. I have this bit of code:

```
$html =~ m{
    ( # $1 the whole tag
        <
        (
            ?:
            !--
            ( # $2 the attributes are all the data between
                .*?
            )
            --
            | # or
            (
                ?:
                ( # $3 the name of the tag
                    /?\S+?\b
                )
                ( # $4 the attributes
                    [^'">]*
                    (
                        ?:
                        ( # $5 just to match quotes
                            ['"]
                        )
                        .*?\5
                        [^'">]*
                    )*
                )
            )
        )
        >
    )
}gsx
```

...and it now gives me this error:

```
A fatal error has occurred:

    In '(?...)', the '(' and '?' must be adjacent in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/
                ( # $1 the whole tag
                    <
                    (
                        ? <-- HERE :
                        !--
                        ( # $2 the attributes are all the data between
                            .*?
                        )
                        --
                        | # or
                        (
                            ?:
                            ( # $3 the name of the tag
                                /?\S+?\b
                            )
                            ( # $4 the attributes
                                [^'">]*
                                (
                                    ?:
                                    ( # $5 just to match quotes
                                        ['"]
                                    )
                                    .*?\5
                                    [^'">]*
                                )*
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    >
                )
            / at ./admin/GT/HTML/Parser.pm line 207.
    Compilation failed in require at (eval 25) line 8.

Please enable debugging in setup for more details.
```

I'm not really sure what it's complaining about. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot tear those parts apart, that is all. Even when using `x` modifier. See https://ideone.com/U7Vfkh. The non-capturing group markers must go right after `(`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - so just move it all onto one string then? This is how it always used to work, so I guess that must be a change in this version of Perl? ...and wow, that was a super fast response! haha

Comment: Not all in one line, just `(?:`.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick :) Thanks guys! If someone could post an answer, then I'll accept Wiktors (as he got in just before), but if you also post one PerlDuck, then I'll upvote it :) That has to be a record... 5 minutes from posting, and all fixed!

Comment: I'm really not sure how that error message could be any clearer. @AndrewNewby, do you have any suggestions on how we could rephrase it?

Comment: @DaveCross ??? Are you asking how to rephrase the subject?

Comment: @AndrewNewby: No, I'm asking how you think the error message you could be made clearer. I thought it was very clear; you obviously didn't. You are therefore in a really good position to help improve Perl by suggesting improvements to the error message.

Comment: @DaveCross - I had done a 14 hour day, so nothing was very clear ;) Reading back now (knowing the answer), and I can see what it was saying

Comment: @AndrewNewby: So the only potential improvement you're suggesting is to preface it with "if this seems to make no sense to you, try getting a good eight hours sleep and reading it again in the morning" :-)

Comment: @DaveCross - sounds like a good call ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure `?:` (the non-capturing group markers) go *right after the opening parenthesis* **even when `x` modifier is used**.

See the fixed regex declaration:

```
$html =~ m{
    ( # $1 the whole tag
        <
        (?:
            !--
            ( # $2 the attributes are all the data between
                .*?
            )
            --
            | # or
            (?:
                ( # $3 the name of the tag
                    /?\S+?\b
                )
                ( # $4 the attributes
                    [^'">]*
                    (?:
                        ( # $5 just to match quotes
                            ['"]
                        )
                        .*?\5
                        [^'">]*
                    )*
                )
            )
        )
        >
    )
}gsx
```

See [this reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%2Fx):

> Note that anything inside a `\Q...\E` stays unaffected by `/x`. And note that `/x` doesn't affect space interpretation within a single multi-character construct. For example in `\x{...}`, regardless of the `/x` modifier, there can be no spaces. Same for a quantifier such as `{3}` or `{5,}`. **Similarly, `(?:...)` can't have a space between the `"{"` , `"?"` , and `":"`**. Within any delimiters for such a construct, allowed spaces are not affected by `/x`, and depend on the construct. For example, `\x{...}` can't have spaces because hexadecimal numbers don't have spaces in them.

I think there is a typo - `{` must be actually `(`. I bolded the part of text that is relevant for the current scenario.